# For-loop Length Local Variable Micro Optimization?

Tags: language-agnostic, for-loop, micro-optimization

In a lot of programming languages and their micro-optimizations, I've seen that declaring the length of an array within a for-loop has performance implications especially in PHP and JavaScript:

```
for i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; ++i
```

I've seen this format used in C++ and some Java source codes as well. Is this micro-optimization true for all programming languages? If this is a language-agnostic micro optimization, shouldn't it already be optimized from within compilers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I thought that the Java compiler will take care about this kind of optimization, but it isn't so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = new String[10000000];
    Arrays.fill(array, "Test");
    long startNoSize = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    for(int i=0; i< array.length;i++)
    {
        array[i]=String.valueOf(i+1);
    }
    long finishNoSize = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println(finishNoSize-startNoSize);
    System.out.println("Size saved");
    int length = array.length;
    long startSize = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    for(int i=0; i< length;i++)
    {
        array[i]=String.valueOf(i+2);
    }
    long finishSize = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println(finishSize-startSize);
}
```

After some consecutive runs the result is like this:

```
6207
Size saved
4594
```

So there is a difference of 1500 milliseconds.

**UPDATE**
When the loops are reversed, the result is reversed too :)
So there is no issue with lack of optimization.

So the in Java the calling of Container.size doesn't affect the performance.

Comment: Same result with my computer but nevertheless wrong. Switch both test cases and it will be exactly the other way round. So actually a proplem of "cold" jre.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for the compiler is to know that `arr.length` will return the same every iteration in the loop. Sometimes it does not, for example, when the loop body inserts new elements into `arr`.

Comment: I understand the point of not using this format but it's one of the most common for-loop implementations for non-mutating routines. The format is just tedious and spans across text-editors. I hoped that at least one compiler could have optimized this (for-each loops are arbitrary because they do not guarantee order).